# Mysql-Server installation stuck on root password

Tags: mysql, docker

I trying to install `mysql-server` into a `Docker` container so in my Dockerfile I've added `apt-get install mysql-server` , install runs until it demand to provide the root user's password and then just stuck there and nothing happens even when I provide a blank password.

```
Configuring mysql-server-5.5


While not mandatory, it is highly recommended that you set a password for the 
MySQL administrative "root" user.

If this field is left blank, the password will not be changed.

New password for the MySQL "root" user:
```

I don't know if it's a bug or if it have anything to do with docker
Anyone encountered this before ?

Comment: Can you add the contents of your Dockerfile to the question?

Comment: Have you considered using an official image? https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Comment: Indeed I've solved this by using the official image in a seperate container then using `docker-compose` , but installing `mysql` into another image like `ubuntu` or `debian` never worked to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to set the password *before* installing MySQL:

```
# MySQL
ENV MYSQL_PWD Pwd123
RUN echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $MYSQL_PWD" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $MYSQL_PWD" | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get -y install mysql-server
```